# How to compute Hair Curves tilts after Deform Curves on Surface node?

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, geometry, hair

Hair object is incredibly useful for controlled scattering of anything along the surface of a mesh, like hair (duh)... unless you have to animate deformations of said mesh (Hair on a Character).
Then you discover that the spin/tilt of instances/hairs is not preserved by Deform Curves on Surface Node. Which is ok only for circular hair, but not feathers, card hair, sculpetd hair, or even micro-textured hair etc.

Visual huntch suggests one should store initial/deformed tangents/normals on points of interest and somehow that might be enough to compute orientation of what's in those interest points along the surface.

["higgsas" on devtalk has suggested a way to compute tangents of points on a mesh](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/geometry-nodes/16108/2732?u=kivig)
:
[image: Getting some sort of tangents]

Also that can be done before deformations and stored for computation after.
However how would one compute the deformations of hair curves tilt according to those changes in tangents/normals?

The manual for Deform Curves on Surface Node mentions that it has:

> a few implicit inputs:
> ...A 3D vector attribute named rest_position, used for calculating tangents >for rotating curves that are consistent with the tangents calculated on the >original mesh (the rotation needs to be calculated from the normal and >tangent of the original and evaluated meshes).

However there seems to not be much information in this regard out there.